# Rails Jquery not allowing nested model forms to work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I inherited a rails application using a nested model form(as in railscast 197). The application is using jquery 2.0.0.

If I have just jquery 2.0.0 included flot charts work properly but I am unable to add fields in the form.
Then by mistake I included jquery twice and the forms somehow started working properly and flot charts were gone!

Any sort of help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. It was due to the incorrect order in the assets pipeline.